# How to separate Fullname into several parts

Tags: sql-server

I have this problem recently when I have to separate the Fullname into 4 parts. `Firstname, Middle name/Initial, Lastname and Suffix`. I'm having a hard time with this. Please help.

```
Declare @name varchar(100)
set @name = 'Michael John T. Mac Tavish, Jr.'
SELECT @name, substring(@name, 1,charindex(' ',@name)) as firstname,
        left(ltrim(substring(@name, charindex(' ',@name),len(@name)-charindex(' ',@name)+1)),2) as MiddleName,
        substring(@name, len(@name)-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@name))+1, len(@name)) as lastname
```

Comment: What's your question? Does it not work? What's your expected result?

Comment: how to separate firstname as 'Michael John', MiddleInitial as 'T.', Lastname as 'Mac Tavish', and Suffix as 'Jr.'. The code above is not separating it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your sql code with the below one -

```
Declare @name varchar(100)
set @name = 'Michael John T. Mac Tavish, Jr.'
SELECT  @name as Name,
        rtrim(ltrim(substring(@name,1,dbo.pos(@name,' ',2)))) as firstname,
        rtrim(ltrim(substring(@name,dbo.pos(@name,' ',2)+1,charindex('.',@name)-dbo.pos(@name,' ',2)))) as MiddleName,
        rtrim(ltrim(substring(@name,charindex('.',@name)+1,charindex(',',@name)-charindex('.',@name)-1))) as lastname,
        rtrim(ltrim(substring(@name,charindex(',',@name)+1,len(@name)))) as Suffix
```

Function code to find the nth occurrence of a character in a string -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Pos(@string VARCHAR(MAX),@delim VARCHAR(1),@occur INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos int, @counter int, @ret int
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string)
set @counter = 1
if @occur = 1 set @ret = @pos
else
begin
while (@counter < @occur)
begin
select @ret = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string, @pos + 1)
set @counter = @counter + 1
set @pos = @ret
end
end
RETURN @ret
END
```

But I would really suggest you to re-frame your question and provide more information (your string patterns, how you are identifying the delimiters to extract the name parts etc...) to solve the problem more effectively.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek for sharing your idea. I should rephrase my question to make it clear. Your solution is working but i still got some errors regarding to the firstname, 'Mark Gregory Kevin T. Mac Tavish' Asian names are too long. Mark Gregory Kevin is the first name which I find difficult to separate.

Comment: What was the error, post it here and if the names are too long all you can do is increase the size of the data type. Anyways you need to give more details on how you want to segregate the FirstName and all....